# Ubuntu to RHEL C++ cross-compilation (64bits)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, c++11, cross-compiling, rhel

Not exactly sure where this question belongs, let me know if I should move it.

Here is the issue; over the past years I have a put together a relatively large personal codebase in C++11 that I'm using for work, but my workplace runs supposedly the latest version of RHEL on their cluster, which runs gcc 4.4.7, which supports C++11 only partially.

I have battled to get a decent compiler installed, but apparently there is no easy way of making this happen, so instead I am wondering whether it would be possible to cross-compile C++11 sources on my own desktop, and export the executable on the cluster at my workplace. I just don't know where to start in order to do that:

1. Is it possible (and how) to cross-compile C++11 sources from Ubuntu to RHEL?
2. Since I am at it, is it possible to rebuild gcc 4.8 or a suitable `libstdc++` (or `libc++`) entirely from Ubuntu to an rpm package compatible with RHEL?

*(Note: I would preferably use clang (3.4) to compile on my desktop, but gcc (4.8) would be fine too.)*

Comment: How about building an Ubuntu chroot that would contain your application. You could deploy this chroot on the RHEL hosts that are part of your cluster.

Comment: @ChristopheVu-Brugier That sounds good but I have close to no experience with chroot (the only time I used it was to repair the boot table on a partition from a live system). Would you please care to elaborate in an answer?

Comment: You create a chroot with debootstrap on your Ubuntu workstation, install your application in it, make a tarball of the resulting chroot and copy it on a RHEL host. Here are some information about the debootstrap step: http://www.debian-administration.org/article/426/Installing_new_Debian_systems_with_debootstrap

Comment: @ChristopheVu-Brugier So if I understand correctly, it would be like running Ubuntu within RHEL on the same machine. I would then be able to compile my source code from within the Ubuntu chroot, copy the executable outside in RHEL, and run it from there. Correct?

Comment: Correct. The chroot allows to satisfy the dependencies of your application (ie a system with a recent libstdc++ compatible with the one found on your workstation) while running on RHEL.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the hardest part is to isolate the dependencies necessary for compiling then.

Comment: What solution you've ultimately went with?

Comment: @DanM. I gave up and waited for a newer compiler to be installed :) But I think Christophe's suggestion would be great to try — please feel free to post an answer if you do try it!